# adding multiple slices in python

Tags: python, slice

I want to get the slice of `x[start1:stop1:step1 ]` and  `x[start2:stop2:step2]` in a single array.

Is there any syntax in Python like this:

```
x[start1:stop1:step1  +  start2:stop2:step2]
```

In Matlab it is simply:

```
x(start1:step1:stop1  start2:step2:stop2)
```

update:

I see many answers suggest concatenation.

My intial goal is to do slice for **higher dimension array**, for example in 2D:

```
x[start1:stop1 +  start2:stop2,  start3:stop3  +  start4:stop4]
```

Concatenation is okay. But it seems too complicated in high dimension.

Is there a way as simple as Matlab?

```
x(start1:stop1  start2:stop2, start3:stop3  start4:stop4 )
```

**can we concatenate the array index, instead of the array itself?**

[see my solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50693906/6935897)

[image: the Tartan]

Comment: Do you have numpy? Are you going to use it?

Comment: It would be simpler to understand with a concrete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
D1=list(range(start1,stop1,step1))+list(range(start2,stop2,step2))
D2=list(range(start3,stop3,step3))+list(range(start4,stop4,step4))+"add more if you want"
x[D1,:][:,D2]
```

the effect is to select out the black regions in this Tartan pattern, from the whole cloth.

[image: arbitary cut]

for example, `test` is a 2D array.

`D1` and `D2` are some list of index in column and row. We wannt some cut

```
import numpy as np
test=np.random.random((20,20))
D1=list(range(1,8,2))+list(range(1,9,3))
D2=list(range(1,9,3))+list(range(2,10,3))
print(test[D1,:].shape)
print(test[:,D2].shape)
# test[D1,D2] will create error
output=test[D1,:][:,D2]
type(output)
output.shape
```

However, it is still unclear, why doesn't  `test[D1,D2]` work.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate two arrays (lists) like this: `x[start1:stop1:step1]  +  x[start2:stop2:step2]`

Comment: This will work for lists but it won't concatenate arrays, it will add them together

Answer (score 1):

This operation is also pretty easy in python. Once you've defined the list you can do your like this:

```
new_list = lst[start1:stop1:step1] + lst[start2:stop2:step2]
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer indicates you are using `numpy`, so you can use [`r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html#numpy.r_) for this instead of constructing ranges.

```
test=np.random.random((20,20))
test[np.r_[1:8:2, 1:9:3], :][:, np.r_[1:9:3, 2:10:3]]
```

Indexing multidimensional arrays using sequences has been designed to [work a bit differently](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) from indexing using slices. e.g. `test[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]` will return an array containing `test[0, 3], test[1, 4], test[2, 5]`. That's why `test[D1, D2]` in your answer doesn't work.

If you want a slightly more convenient syntax you could make a class extending `ndarray` with an altered method for handling indices:

```
class MultiArray(np.ndarray):
    """ An array that can be indexed by multiple lists or arrays of indices
    in the same way as by slices e.g.
    m = MultiArray([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
    m[[1, 2], [0, 3, 2]]  # returns [[5, 8, 7], [9, 12, 11]]

    Returns a standard array.
    """
    def __new__(cls, input_array):
        return np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        r = np.array(self)
        if type(key) is tuple:
            for dimension, index in enumerate(key):
                indices = [slice(None)] * len(key)
                indices[dimension] = index
                r = r[tuple(indices)]
            return r
        else:
            return r[key]     

print(MultiArray(test)[np.r_[1:8:2, 1:9:3], np.r_[1:9:3, 2:10:3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating the two lists, as in [Jonas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50692283/908494), is the simplest solution, and usually the best.

If you're worried about making temporary lists, you can do something slightly more complicated, like:

```
[elem for i, elem in enumerate(x) 
 if i in range(start1, stop1, step1) or i in range(start2, stop2, step2)]
```

… or:

```
list(itertools.chain(itertools.islice(x, start1, stop1, step1),
                     itertools.islice(x, start2, stop2, step2)))
```

However, I'd expect either one to be a whole lot slower unless the two sublists are so huge that memory allocation time dominates everything, and of course they're a lot more complicated and less readable.

The only real advantage of either of these solutions is if you don't actually need the list, you can turn them into lazy iterators easily:

```
(elem for i, elem in enumerate(x) 
 if i in range(start1, stop1, step1) or i in range(start2, stop2, step2))

itertools.chain(itertools.islice(x, start1, stop1, step1),
                itertools.islice(x, start2, stop2, step2))
```

(In fact, the second one is just the lazy equivalent of Jonas's answer: `islice(x, start1, stop1, step1)` does the same thing as `x[start1:stop1:step1]`, and `chain(a, b)` does the same thing as `a + b`.)

Answer (score -2):

Concatenate is a great way, or alternatively, you can join the two lists

```
part1 = x[start1:stop1:step1]
part2 = x[start2:stop2:step2]
mergedlist = part1 + part2

mergedlist = list(set(part1 + part2))
```

This will create a merged list, with a shallow copy of the items in the first list, followed by a shallow copy of the items in the second list.

If you want deep copy, you may use copy.deepcopy commands.

Comment: Can you explain how this is different from the other two answers aside from just splitting it into multiple lines?

Comment: Great question, I can not realize other people have posted the answer, so great, I can provide a new way using set, which gives actually the same..... Time is the issue, this can not blame me though.

Comment: Your answer says "Concatenate is a great way, or alternatively, you can join the two lists", so obviously you think you've written an alternative to ccncatenation, but you haven't, you've written the sam thing. And your second answer just concatenates, then converts the result to a set and back to a list, which has no effect except to take longer, lose duplicates, scramble the order, and raise an exception if the elements aren't hashable.

Comment: "I can provide a new way using set, which gives actually the same" nope.